# My button in html not responding to my js

Tags: javascript, html

So i am learning javascript and i am checking out js reactiong to my html button and this does not seem to work it always says "cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'log')"

Here's my code:

Html:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title></title>

</head>
<label>name: </label>
<input type= text id ="mytext">
<button type=button id= "mybutton"> submit</button>
<body>
<script src = index.js></script>
 </body>
</html>`
```

Js:

```
    let name = undefined;

document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = function(){

    let name = document.getElementById("mytext")
}

console.log(name);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it say `console.log(name)` instead of `console.console.log(name)`?

Comment: And shouldn't that line be placed inside the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is sth like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Input Field Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="input-field">
    <button onclick="logInput()">Log Input</button>
    <script>
      function logInput() {
        const input = document.getElementById("input-field").value;
        console.log(input);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your code has two simple bugs, or wrong usages.

1. you need to add `.value` after `document.getElementById("mytext")`
2. Not `console.console.log(name)` but `console.log(name)`

Comment: .. and yes you can do the script inline or in an extra file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>name: </label>
<input type="text" id ="mytext">
<button type="button" id= "mybutton"> submit</button>


<!-- <script src = index.js></script> -->


<script>//here i am using internal script you may use your script in your way 
document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = function(){
    let name = document.getElementById("mytext").value;
console.log(name);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dumping code into an answer is not useful. Please add some notes/commentary to your answer to show _what_ you've changed to solve the problem, and _why_.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:
html code:

```
<div id="myelement">
<button type="button" id="mybutton">Show Text</button>
<input type="text" id="mytext"></input>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = function(){

    text = document.getElementById("mytext").value;

  console.log(text); 
 
}
```

use call the console log inside the function. also you have duplicated  console `console.console.log(name);` you should use `console.log(name);`

here is the jsfiddle test : https://jsfiddle.net/qxucho84/